# C programming array index out of bound

Tags: c, arrays, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

Please give your view about array out of bounds....if i m taking big array output is correct bit for 20 array size....printing garbage value

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int message[200],i,j,n,count,temp;
    count=0;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    //input taking line
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
        scanf("%d",&message[i]);
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        if(message[i]==1)
        {
            count+=1;
        }
        if(message[i]==0)
            count=0;

        if(count==5)
        {
            count=0;
            temp=message[i+1];
            message[i+1]=0;
            //n=n+1;
            //n1=n;
            for(j=(n); j<(i+2); j--)
            {
                message[j+1]=message[j];
            }
            n++;
            message[i+2]=temp;
        }
    }

    printf("line\n");
    //n1+=1;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",message[i]);
    }
    //n1+=1;
    return 0;

}
```

thanks for any help...

Answer (score 2):

In C, array indexing starts from `0`. Your loop should look like this:

```
 for(i=0;i<n;i++) {...}
```

Comment: still it shows same error if i take big array..no garbage value....else it shows garbage value

Comment: You can't take value for `n` larger than `200`.

Comment: you try to run program with all i,j starting with zero.....and take array size 20 and n=8 ...run it...dn give solution